# MySQL Where clause not returning any results

Tags: mysql, database

[image]

Above is the image of my column.
I am trying to get data according to that column values.

```
$sql = "select * from site WHERE region='NORTHGUJARAT'";
```

This works and shows the north gujarat rows BUT,

```
$sql = "select * from site WHERE region='SOUTHGUJARAT'";
```

This query does not show any rows even though the value is present in the column.
I tried on both PHPMYADMIN SQL and through PHP also. I see the records of "NORTHGUJARAT" but i cannot see the records of "SOUTHGUJARAT"
What is the problem here?

Comment: `$sql = "select * from site WHERE region LIKE %SOUTHGUJARAT%";`  try once in phpmyadmin and check. if not working then post your table with that data

Comment: check for space in values.

Comment: You might have a white space at the end  "SOUTHGUJARAT ", Using Like "SOUTHGUJARAT%" will probably solve your problem but it wont solve the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. Thanks for the reply
I had copy pasted the value from an excel cell and then inserted from the PHPMYADMIN interface so i guess that was the problem.
I cleared the column and then added the values from PHP code. Now it works fine.